# python import csv file with both chinese character and latin character

Tags: python, csv

everyone, I'm doing some research in animal protection. I've collected some animal species data, it contains Chinese character as well as other non-english characters. for instance

中文名 .   拉丁名 .                                  cites附录等级

蜂猴 Nycticebus bengalensis (Lacépède, 1800)   Ⅰ

倭蜂猴   Nycticebus pygmaeus Bonhote, 1907         Ⅰ

I'm not sure which encoding to choose from ,any help ? thanks a lot 

`with open('animal_protection.csv',encoding = "utf-8") as csvDataFile:`

Comment: UTF-8 should work.

Comment: no,it doesn't work, there are some latin words in my file, if i use utf-8,it produce 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTF-8 has no problem, I have done a test and below is the code and result:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame()
data[u"中文名"] = [u"蜂猴 ", u"倭蜂猴"]
data[u"拉丁名"] = [u"Nycticebus bengalensis", u"Nycticebus pygmaeus Bonhote"]
data[u"cites附录等级"] = [1800, 1907]

data.to_csv("animals.csv")

data_read = pd.read_csv("animals.csv")
print(data_read)
#print(data_read[u"中文名"])
#print(data_read[u"拉丁名"])
#print(data_read[u"cites附录等级"])

   Unnamed: 0  中文名                          拉丁名  cites附录等级
0           0  蜂猴        Nycticebus bengalensis       1800
1           1  倭蜂猴  Nycticebus pygmaeus Bonhote       1907
```

Comment: This is just a little example to show that there is no encoding error in program. You can adjust the output by changing the code from your needs.

Comment: thanks Alex, I'll try your method on the entire data, the character above will produce no error, will update the result soon